# How to test on specific version of IE11

Tags: installation, internet-explorer

One of our old machine has older version of IE 11 and our feature doesn't work on that version. However on my local machine which has the latest version of IE 11 and it does work. I tried different emulation mode on IE as well as edge.

How can I test locally for the older IE 11 version?

[image]

**Update**: turns out this version of IE is not supported by the Microsoft and this question is irrelevant. However on Windows Server 2012 I couldn't find a way to update IE 11.

Created another question: [How to update IE 11.0.9600 in Windows Server 2012 (OS Version: Windows NT 6.2)](https://superuser.com/q/1299587/138919)

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to just update the version of IE installed on the machine?  You do understand the system in question, has not received a single update in over a year, right?  *Any event you would have to create an SP1 installation of Windows 7, then install up to, the KB your current machine has installed.*  There is no easy way to do that.

Comment: That particular version of IE is unsupported by Microsoft.

Comment: As Manoj mentioned I want to make sure that any client using older version of IE 11 should be good with our app. Officially we support IE 11 and I guess saying that we only support latest version of IE11 would be somewhat big ask. @Ramhound, any resources?

Comment: @Rohit - Resources for what?  Install Windows  7 SP1 and install all updates through that KB you have installed on the system in question.  You realize there are dozens upon dozens of versions of IE11, are you going to test them all, there are tools to emulate specific versions of IE11 I suggest that instead.

Comment: Hey, @Ramhound. Didn't mean to offend you. I was just asking if there is any article where it mentions IE 11.0.9600 is unsupported.

Comment: Microsoft only supports the current version of IE11 on Windows 7.  That is documented by the support cycle of Windows 7/IE11. I don't have a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get multiple versions of IE installed on different OSs as VMs from Microsoft: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Using VirtualBox/VMware/Vagrant, you can set it up pretty easily, and run your tests.

Here are the different versions available: [image]

Comment: This is not helpful. The OP asks about specific minor version (or even a specific build) of IE 11, not about ability to test specific major version.